# React Ace intellisense as user types

Tags: reactjs, intellisense, ace-editor

Currently it has the shortcut combination of CTRL + Space in Windows and CMD + Space in Mac.

I need the React Ace Editor, to show autocomplete intellisense as user types .(dot)